# Custom fields with sub-fields in Solr 1.4

Tags: solr, custom-fields

does anyone know how to create a custom field in solr 1.4? I need to create a field containing sub values of the same type, say 3 strings.

The problem is abt something like this: suppose i want to declare in the schema an "image" field, which has 3 sub-fields (strings) like "path", "title", "thumb_path".

Any ideas?

I know in solr 1.5 there will be probably the concept of LatLon object, to contain the 2 values -doubles- of latitude and longitude. Have you seen something like that?

Luca

Comment: why not use three separate fields? or why not use a multiValued field?

Comment: +1 to what Mauricio said. SOLR is not a relational DB, its more like a noSQL database so you have to think of it like a single flat/de-normalised table.

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for the answers. Well, actually the problem is that this operation needs to be done on a multivalue field :) Say for instance that I want to index/store the information to build a gallery. A gallery is done by many images, and for every image i have 3 different information (path, thumb_path and title). I'm not able to know how many images a single gallery could have, and i dont want to set a limit (say, max 10 images per gallery).

Comment: what are you searching for? images or galleries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you should consider creating an index of "image" documents in your SOLR index.

Each image "doc" would have the fields:

- title
- path
- thumb_path
- [gallery]

where [gallery] is a multi-value field (assuming images can appear in more than one gallery)

To construct a gallery page, you run the query "gallery:foo" and then iterate over the list of images, populating the HTML elements from the fields: title, path, etc.

Note: SOLR does not limit you to having a single document type in its index (whether its best practice is another matter). So you could also index other non-image documents as well. In this case its advisable to have a field like "doc_type" so you can limit searches to that type

Comment: The solution you're suggesting me seems interesting, even if i dont have a real probability to have images shared in different galleries. The only thing i dont like too much is to have a sort of duplication in sizes of element stored (imagine that galleries are just a part of a more complex object, which has thousand of instances in my case). BTW, thank you.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, the duplication you refer to is an unavoidable consequence of the NoSQL-like approach that SOLR takes. The benefit is scalability (sub second response times even when your data grows 100x, the cost is having to deal with de-referenced data (and possible duplication of "joined" fields). 

You could decide not to put this data in SOLR and just use it for the full-text search functionality (relevance ranking, stemming, facets, term boosting). Keeping the gallery/image lookups in a relational DB instead. Might even make sense if scalability is not an issue.